# Basic process for copying staging to fact and dimension tables

Tags: sql, database, etl

I don't have a great deal of experience with ETL processes for staging data from one system into a BI data warehouse. I am very familiar and confident with SQL, just not how to engineer a process to load data that does not already exist.

I have three fields of data I would like to load

1. Lotdetid (business key)
2. Fromdp (foreign key)
3. Dp (foreign key)

`Lotdetid` is from a transactional table.

`Fromdp` and `Dp` are foreign keys to a static table that rarely changes.

I want to load all `Lotdetids` with associated `fromdp` and `dp` keys into the DWH.

After I stage this data, how can I load it into relevant fact and Dimension tables ready to use in my data warehouse?

Comment: 1. Which kind of platform do you operate on? 

2. Are you limited to do it in database or do you have any ETL software available?

in databases you could write a stored procedure that select the data through a view and insert it into fact and dimension tables. Stored procedures allow you to create error handling.

Detecting new and updated records can be easily identified using the the Lotdetid key. Hard part is how to detect and handle deletes, especially from dimension tables.

Comment: I am using sql server and have access to stored procedures as well as SSIS. I'm familiar with the basics of SSIS, but have never created an ETL package to empty a bunch of BI tables, stage the data from source and and load into fact tables.

Comment: with full loads: truncate table, first load dimension tables. then use a view to load the fact table. works for both SSIS and Stored procedures

Comment: With delta loads, things become a lot harder. how can you detect deletes and updates, how to handle deletes of dimension values where fact tables are depending on these dimension values etc..  A lot more information is needed to setup a solid delta load mechanism